# Marker Google Maps puxa só 1 endereço entre vários

Tags: javascript, api, google, maps, marker

Estou utilizando a API do Google Maps para fazer um mapa com markers em cima do endereço que informo e também um auto complete no `input`. O problema é que se eu ponho por exemplo o endereço da minha casa no input e ele coloca o marker em cima do endereço de casa, ao clicar no marker ele exibe um endereço de **valinhos - São Paulo**. O site já está no ar aqui: http://www.brasilpark.com.br/unidades

Os endereços, só deixei 1 porque tenho MUITOS e aqui ficaria ruim.

**mapa.js**

```
var geocoder;
var map;
var marker;
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

var markers = [{"Estado":"Goiás","Cidade":"Goiânia","Bairro":"Jardim Goiás","Unidade":"CARREFOUR GOIÂNIA SUL","Endereco":"Avenida Deputado Jamel Cecílio, 3900 - Jardim Goías - Goiânia - GO","Lat":"-16.7093680","Lng":"-49.2325750"}];

function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-23.5557040,-46.6627530);
    var options = {
        zoom: 5,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        mapTypeControl: false
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapa"), options);

    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        draggable: true
    });

    marker.setPosition(latlng);


     var infoWindowContent = [
        ['<div class="info_content">' +
        '<h3>London Eye</h3>' +
        '<p>The London Eye is a giant Ferris wheel situated on the banks of the River Thames. The entire structure is 135 metres (443 ft) tall and the wheel has a diameter of 120 metres (394 ft).</p>' +        '</div>'],
        ['<div class="info_content">' +
        '<h3>Palace of Westminster</h3>' +
        '<p>The Palace of Westminster is the meeting place of the House of Commons and the House of Lords, the two houses of the Parliament of the United Kingdom. Commonly known as the Houses of Parliament after its tenants.</p>' +
        '</div>']
    ];

    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

       for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
        var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i].Lat, markers[i].Lng);
        bounds.extend(position);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: position,
            map: map,
            title: markers[i].Unidade
        });

        // Allow each marker to have an info window
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
                infoWindow.setContent('<h1>'+markers[i].Unidade+'</h1>'+'<br /><br />'+markers[i].Endereco);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));

        // Automatically center the map fitting all markers on the screen
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }




}

$(document).ready(function () {

    initialize();

    function carregarNoMapa(endereco) {
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': endereco + ', Brasil', 'region': 'BR' }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                if (results[0]) {
                    var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                    var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

                    $('#txtEndereco').val(results[0].formatted_address);
                    $('#txtLatitude').val(latitude);
                    $('#txtLongitude').val(longitude);

                    var location = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                    marker.setPosition(location);
                    map.setCenter(location);
                    map.setZoom(16);
                }
            }
        })
    }

    $("#btnEndereco").click(function() {
        if($(this).val() != "")
            carregarNoMapa($("#txtEndereco").val());
    })

    $("#txtEndereco").blur(function() {
        if($(this).val() != "")
            carregarNoMapa($(this).val());
    })

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function () {
        geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': marker.getPosition() }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                if (results[0]) {
                    $('#txtEndereco').val(results[0].formatted_address);
                    $('#txtLatitude').val(marker.getPosition().lat());
                    $('#txtLongitude').val(marker.getPosition().lng());
                }
            }
        });
    });

    $("#txtEndereco").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            geocoder.geocode({ 'address': request.term + ', Brasil', 'region': 'BR' }, function (results, status) {
                response($.map(results, function (item) {
                    return {
                        label: item.formatted_address,
                        value: item.formatted_address,
                        latitude: item.geometry.location.lat(),
                        longitude: item.geometry.location.lng()
                    }
                }));
            })
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $("#txtLatitude").val(ui.item.latitude);
            $("#txtLongitude").val(ui.item.longitude);
            var location = new google.maps.LatLng(ui.item.latitude, ui.item.longitude);
            marker.setPosition(location);
            map.setCenter(location);
            map.setZoom(16);
        }
    });

    $("form").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var endereco = $("#txtEndereco").val();
        var latitude = $("#txtLatitude").val();
        var longitude = $("#txtLongitude").val();

        alert("Endereço: " + endereco + "\nLatitude: " + latitude + "\nLongitude: " + longitude);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Acho que existe a necessidade de você redeclarar o evento click na função *carregaNoMapa()*

Daí ela ficaria assim:

```
function carregarNoMapa(endereco) {
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': endereco + ', Brasil', 'region': 'BR' }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if (results[0]) {
                var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

                $('#txtEndereco').val(results[0].formatted_address);
                $('#txtLatitude').val(latitude);
                $('#txtLongitude').val(longitude);

                var location = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                marker.setPosition(location);
                map.setCenter(location);
                map.setZoom(16);

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker) {
                    return function() {
                        infoWindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
                        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                    }
                })(marker));
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Ou para não repetir, você coloca o addListener em uma outra função e chama ela passando o parâmetro no *marker* e o template do *infoWindow*

Espero ter ajudado.